# How to create an insert Form with TextInput containing ComboBox provided by mySQL Database Table

Tags: mysql, database, apache-flex, forms, combobox

I have a Flex application which manage a database composed by 7 tables.
I have created the insert form and all work great. Now I wanto to improve the Form performances; the idea is to replace the TextInput of the Form with ComboBoxes which are provided by the DataBase tables. Any ideas?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to query the subtables and send back the resultsets to the client. Once you have all data you need, you'll need to write the code that relates the foreign keys of your form entity to the primary keys of your subtables.